# how to subscribe to a function, which observes @Published?

Tags: swiftui, combine

It is required to dynamically render messages list in a SwiftUI body block:

```
 var chatSpace: some View {
        List(self.viewModel.getMessages(), id: \.self) { message in
            message
        }
 }
```

where view model, is the instance of the following class:

```
class MessagesListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @ObservedObject var messageService: MessageService
    
    init(messageService: MessageService) {
        self.messageService = messageService
    }
    
    func getMessages() -> [MessageView] {
        return self.messageService.messages.map {
            return MessageView(message: $0)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

I want to reflect changes when I update MessageService `message` property, how can I achieve that? Can I somehow subscribe to the changes? Right now, I'm basically adding a message by updating `messages` published var, however, it does not trigger re-drawing

```
class MessageService: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var messages: [Message] = [Message]()
    
    func addMessage(_ sender: String, _ text: String, _ time: String) {
        self.messages.append(Message(sender: sender, text: text, time: time))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now, I'm basically adding a message by updating messages published var, however, it does not trigger re-drawing

because `@ObservedObject var messageService: MessageService` does nothing in `MessagesListViewModel`, as `@ObservedObject` designed to be in View but not in View Model.

So the solution should be like (separated view for messages)

```
struct ChatSpace: some View {
   @ObservedObject var messageService: MessageService    // << view observes messages

   var body: some View {
      List(messageService.messages, id: \.self) {
            MessageView(message: $0)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! but how would I deal with that if that would be a function, not an observed object? Let's say, it is required to wrap plain data in a view? is it possible to somehow call a function in a body, or subscribe to that function?

Comment: @Ilja, it can be called function in a body if it returns some View, but observed must always be inside view. The preferred approach is to separate into another view than to use function, because in first case SwiftUI rendering engine has better ability for optimisation.